# Dynamic sheet reference in the MATCH function

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, match

I'm trying to figure out how/if I can make a dynamic worksheet reference to the MATCH function.

I have 12 data sheets (Jan-Dec) and one comparison sheet. On each data sheet I have a number of projects and basic info for each project (Revenue, Gross margin etc). The project list is not fixed, projects can be added or removed between the data sheets and the order of the projects can change.

On the overview sheet I want to be able compare any two datasheets by selecting the month.

I manage to the point of picking up data from the correct worksheet with the formula below (cell `$D$2` holds the reference to the period).

`=INDIRECT("'"&$D$2&"'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH($A36;Jan!$A:$A;0);MATCH($D$5&POC!D$6;Jan!$A$4:$AR$4;0))`

The problem is the `MATCH($A36;Jan!$A:$A;0)`. When I change the period in `$D$2` to Feb the match still returns the row from Jan.

Is there a way to make the sheet reference in the MATCH function dynamic?

Comment: The answer is already in your formula: `MATCH($A36,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1,1,1,$D$2)&":"&ADDRESS(10000,1)),0)`

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot, I understand more about both INDIRECT and ADDRESS now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, this should work:

`=INDIRECT("'"&$D$2&"'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH($A36;INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;1;1;1;$D$2)&":"&ADDRESS(10000;1));0);MATCH($D$5&POC!D$6;INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4;1;1;1;$D$2)&":"&ADDRESS(4;44));0))`